# Send push notifications using parse

Tags: php, android, ios

I want to send notifications to android as well as ios applications using parse notifications. I am trying this code to send notifications but they are not sent.

Is there something to add to it or any other requirements, such as the need to install PHP SDK for parse?

```
$APPLICATION_ID = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";//Application-Id
$REST_API_KEY = "yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy";//your-api-key
$MESSAGE = "your-alert-message";

if (!empty($_POST)) {

    $errors = array();
    foreach (array('app' => 'APPLICATION_ID', 'api' => 'REST_API_KEY', 'body' => 'MESSAGE') as $key => $var) {
        if (empty($_POST[$key])) {
            $errors[$var] = true;
        } else {
            $$var = $_POST[$key];
        }
    }

    if (!$errors) {
        $url = 'https://api.parse.com/1/push';
        $data = array(
            'where' => '{}',
            'type' => 'android',
            'expiry' => 1451606400,
            'data' => array(
                'alert' => $MESSAGE,
            ),
        );
        $_data = json_encode($data);
        $headers = array(
            'X-Parse-Application-Id: ' . $APPLICATION_ID,
            'X-Parse-REST-API-Key: ' . $REST_API_KEY,
            'Content-Type: application/json',
            'Content-Length: ' . strlen($_data),
        );

        $curl = curl_init($url);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $_data);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        $response = curl_exec($curl);

    }
}
?><!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="de" lang="de">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>Parse API</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php if (isset($response)) {
            echo '<h2>Response from Parse API</h2>';
            echo '<pre>' . htmlspecialchars($response) . '</pre>';
            echo '<hr>';
        } elseif ($_POST) {
            echo '<h2>Error!</h2>';
            echo '<pre>';
            var_dump($APPLICATION_ID, $REST_API_KEY, $MESSAGE);
            echo '</pre>';
        } ?>

        <h2>Send Message to Parse API</h2>
        <form id="parse" action="" method="post" accept-encoding="UTF-8">
            <p>
                <label for="app">APPLICATION_ID</label>
                <input type="text" name="app" id="app" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($APPLICATION_ID); ?>">
            </p>
            <p>
                <label for="api">REST_API_KEY</label>
                <input type="text" name="api" id="api" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($REST_API_KEY); ?>">
            </p>
            <p>
                <label for="api">REST_API_KEY</label>
                <textarea name="body" id="body"><?php echo htmlspecialchars($REST_API_KEY); ?></textarea>
            </p>
            <p>
                <input type="submit" value="send">
            </p>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```